# Помогите переписать POST запрос с PHP на Node js

Tags: php, node.js, post

Как переписать отправку данного POST-запроса с PHP на Node.js?

```
$params = [
    'method' => 'getSynText',
    'text' => 'Синонимизация текста совершенно бесплатно'
];
$ch = curl_init('https://rustxt.ru/api/index.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest",
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$json_arr = json_decode($result, true);

print_r($json_arr);
```

Попробовал сделать так, но пишет undefined:

```
console.log(getPostResponse());

function getPostResponse() {
    request.post({
        url: 'https://rustxt.ru/api/index.php',
        form: {
            method: 'getSynText',
            text: 'Синонимизация текста совершенно бесплатно'
        }
    }, (err, response, body) => {
        if (err) {
            return err;
        }

        return body;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваш пример реализации похож на небезызвестную связку jquery+ajax.

Попробуйте сделать post зарос с использованием axios.

```
import axios from 'axios';

async function getPostResponse() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post({
      url: 'https://rustxt.ru/api/index.php',
      form: {
        method: 'getSynText',
        text: 'Синонимизация текста совершенно бесплатно'
      }
    });

    return response.data;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

}
```